# Timing delay is random for SPI write - read command

Tags: voltage, adc, linux

I am using ioctl() half duplex SPI command (Linux base) to send command and read the ADC result from ADC chip(slave) to a MCU (master). However, the reading of ADC sometime will show me wrong value, out of 1000 data and I get 5 invalid data("255"), roughly 0.5% error.  Is the ADC and SPI should be 100% working all the time? I am not sure what causing the problem.

With logic analyzer, I notice that the delay time between sending and reading ADC result is always not consistent. I am not sure is it a common symptom for SPI communication or what and I suspect this is the root cause for the error reading.

programming step:

1. start ADC
2. delay for ADC completion
3. send read command
   // Inconsistent delay happening between step 3 and 4, even though my coding has not set any delay in between.
4. receive ADC result
5. loop back to step 3 and continue next reading.
   // Inconsistent delay also happening in between step 5 and 3.

The error reading appear every time when the unknown delay time(approx. 1-12ms) is longer than normal. (Normal delay time should be in the range of 40us according to other successful reading)

From website or reading material about SPI, most of them showing the perfect/ideal condition, timing is as accurate as we think it should, but I believe the real application wouldn't be the case. Or I am wrong about it, I am not sure, this is the first time I am trying to implement SPI for data communication in my small project.

Please share your experience if you have encountered the same problem that I am facing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption is that an application which access the SPI port is running on a Linux operating system.  Linux is a real time operating system.  As such, it is not reasonable to expect the application to run uninterrupted.  At any given moment there are likely dozens of applications running on a Linux operating system.  The operating system is using a [time slicing technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29#Time_slice) to allow each application a small amount of processor time.

The application code, in order to read the data dependably, should wait the minimum delay for the data to become valid.  In this way, if the linux operating system did not preempt the application, the delay should be sufficient.

The author has (later) indicated the use of a 6804 multiple cell pack management chip.  This is a complex, self timed, dual ADC with 6:1 multiplexed inputs capable of monitoring up to 12 batteries.  By no means is this a simple ADC chip.

It is unlikely the SPI interface is to blame for data loss.  Rather, as the 6804 is a complex chip, it is likely this is a 6804 management problem.  Either research the 6804 control registers or control of external 6804 pins.

Since there are many register setting and pins to research it would be impossible to suggest a specific solution.  Rather, here are two idea from reading the 6804 specifications:

1. Does the 6804 go to sleep? What did you set t-IDLE to?

> The serial ports (SPI or isoSPI) will enter the low power IDLE state
>   if there is no activity on Port A for a time of t-IDLE. The WAKEUP
>   circuit monitors activity on pins 41 and 42.

2. Is the software timer being managed properly?

> If software timer activates in the middle of RDCFG command, the
>   configuration register group resets as per Table 14. As a result, the
>   read back data from bytes CRFG4 and CRFG5 could be corrupted.

Comment: I am using ltc 6804 to measure the battery voltage. I come to the assumption that longer delay causing error reading because I have tested it by inserting a delay_ms(1000) - 1 second in between step 3 and 4. All reading become invalid in that situation.

Comment: Step 3 to 5 will loop 4 times to read all ADC result and then step 5 back to step 1 every one second(datalogging for voltage measurement every one second). If i insert delay_ms(1000) between step 5 and 3, all reading become invalid too. However, if I insert delay_ms(1000) between step 5 and 1, the error drops to 0.1%. Very strange.

Comment: You are right! t-idle is set inherently in the firmware. The error happen when it occasionally takes longer time (>t-idle) to process the coding. In my case here, the inconsistent delay time between step 3 and 4 which is more than t-idle causing the reading of invalid value. But this is not what I can control isn't it? Is there any work around to force  the process not being interrupted by the OS? It will be no issue if the processing of the program is not interrupted, like you mention LINUX is a real time operating system that implement time slicing technique.

Comment: There are "real time" Linux kernels which, I assume, improve this type of situation.  But I'm not familiar enough with them to advise you.  In honesty, I would likely use an embedded processor to manage the 6804.  Then have the Linux board talk to the embedded processor.  So, you don't see a way to configure the 6804 to make it work with a real time OS? I had thought that t-idle might be adjustable.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that using embedded processor to deal with the 6804 chip is a much wiser choice. The linux board is the board laying around that I thought I could make use of it without the need to invest another hardware for the project. I am thinking to disable the interruption at the critical part of the program, may be it is not a good practice but I think it's worth a try.